# How to center the numbers?

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

```
\begin{table}[h]

\resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{

\begin{tabular}{lcccccccc}

& $U^{MMM}$ & $U^{MMB}$ & $U^{MBM}$ & $U^{MBB}$ & $U^{BBB}$ & $U^{BBM}$ & $U^{BMB}$ & $U^{BMM}$ \\[2ex] \cline{2-9}

$O^{MMM}$ &\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{3;1,75}&2,9375;1,25&\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{2,9375;2}&2,875;1,5&\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{2,75;2}&2,8125;2,5&\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{2,8125;1,75}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{2,875;2,25} \\[2ex] \cline{2-9} 

$O^{MMB}$ &\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{3,25;2}&2,9375;1,5&\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{2,9375;2,375}&2,625;1,875&\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{2;2,375}&2,3125;2,875&\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{2,3125;2}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{2,625;2,5} \\[2ex] \cline{2-9}

$O^{MBM}$ &\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{2,5;2}&2,4375;1,5&\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{2,4375;2,375}&2,375;1,875&\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{2,25;2,375}&2,3125;2,875&\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{2,3125;2}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{2,375;2,5} \\[2ex] \cline{2-9}

$O^{MBB}$ &\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{2,75;2,25}&2,4375;1,75&\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{2,4375;2,75}&2,125;2,25&\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{1,5;2,75}&1,8125;3,25&\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{1,8125;2,25}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{2,125;2,75} \\[2ex] \cline{2-9}

$O^{BBB}$ &\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{3,25;2,75}&2,6875;2,25&\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{2,6875;3,5}&2,125;3&\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{1;3,5}&1,5625;3,5&\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{1,5625;2,75}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{2,125;3,25} \\[2ex] \cline{2-9}

$O^{BBM}$ &\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{3;2,5}&2,6875;2&\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{2,6875;3,125}&2,375;2,25&\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{1,75;3,125}&2,0625;3,125&\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{2,0625;2,5}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{2,375;3} \\[2ex] \cline{2-9}

$O^{BMB}$ &\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{3,75;2,5}&3,1875;2&\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{3,1875;3,125}&2,625;2,25&\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{1,5;3,125}&2,0625;3,125&\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{2,0625;2,5}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{2,625;3} \\[2ex] \cline{2-9}

$O^{BMM}$ &\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{3,5;2,25}&3,1875;1,75&\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{3,1875;2,75}&2,875;2,25&\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{2,25;2,75}&2,5625;3,25&\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{2,5625;2,25}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{2,875;2,75} \\[2ex] \cline{2-9}
\end{tabular}
}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Get rid of all those `[2ex]` and put `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.4}` as first line after `\begin{table}`.

Comment: Please edit your code to make a minimal working example (MWE).  That means add header information, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}` to make the code compilable.  If one row of your table is sufficient to illustrate your problem, then remove the other rows.  This makes it easier for others to assist you.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi Can you make that an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should increase the line-spacing by `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{<somefactor>}`.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}   
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.4}   
\resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{%       
    \begin{tabular}{>{$}l<{$}|*{8}{>{$}c<{$}|}}         
        \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$U^{MMM}$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$U^{MMB}$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$U^{MBM}$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$U^{MBB}$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$U^{BBB}$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$U^{BBM}$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$U^{BMB}$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$U^{BMM}$} \\ \cline{2-9}         
        O^{MMM} & 3;1,75    & 2,9375;1,25 & 2,9375;2     & 2,875;1,5   & 2,75;2     & 2,8125;2,5   & 2,8125;1,75 & 2,875;2,25 \\ \cline{2-9}            
        O^{MMB} & 3,25;2    & 2,9375;1,5  & 2,9375;2,375 & 2,625;1,875 & 2;2,375    & 2,3125;2,875 & 2,3125;2    & 2,625;2,5  \\ \cline{2-9}            
        O^{MBM} &  2,5;2    & 2,4375;1,5  & 2,4375;2,375 & 2,375;1,875 & 2,25;2,375 & 2,3125;2,875 & 2,3125;2    & 2,375;2,5  \\ \cline{2-9}            
        O^{MBB} & 2,75;2,25 & 2,4375;1,75 & 2,4375;2,75  & 2,125;2,25  & 1,5;2,75   & 1,8125;3,25  & 1,8125;2,25 & 2,125;2,75 \\ \cline{2-9}            
        O^{BBB} & 3,25;2,75 & 2,6875;2,25 & 2,6875;3,5   & 2,125;3     & 1;3,5      & 1,5625;3,5   & 1,5625;2,75 & 2,125;3,25 \\ \cline{2-9}            
        O^{BBM} & 3;2,5     & 2,6875;2    & 2,6875;3,125 & 2,375;2,25  & 1,75;3,125 & 2,0625;3,125 & 2,0625;2,5  & 2,375;3    \\ \cline{2-9}            
        O^{BMB} & 3,75;2,5  & 3,1875;2    & 3,1875;3,125 & 2,625;2,25  & 1,5;3,125  & 2,0625;3,125 & 2,0625;2,5  & 2,625;3    \\ \cline{2-9}            
        O^{BMM} & 3,5;2,25  & 3,1875;1,75 & 3,1875;2,75  & 2,875;2,25  & 2,25;2,75  & 2,5625;3,25  & 2,5625;2,25 & 2,875;2,75 \\ \cline{2-9}
    \end{tabular}
}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh, so many lines :-( Egal, +1 ;-)

Comment: @Johannes_B machste nix... I did not get the purpose for that table. It looks more like something for `blkarray`, `\bordermatrix`, and of course `booktabs`