# How can I remove the numbering in the figure environment?

Tags: beamer, floats, numbering

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Title}
\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{picture.jpg}
\caption{Source: something}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

How can I remove the numbering from the caption in the figure environment? I tried with `caption*` and it didn't work.

Comment: Your example does not produce a figure number, when I compile.

Comment: Don't place it inside `figure` environment

Comment: How do I use \caption without figure enviroment?

Comment: `\captionof{figure}{caption goes here}` where `{figure}` is the environment you want `\captionof` to "pretend" to be in.

Comment: Still no change, Figure 1 is still there.

Comment: would you be willing for a solution without `\usepackage{caption}`?

Comment: Yes, if it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here an answer without `\usepackage{caption}`

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{caption}{%
    \insertcaption\par
}
\setbeamertemplate{caption label separator}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Title}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{pic}
\caption{Source: something}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Comments:

1. You don't need `\centering`, `figures` are automatically centred in `beamer`.
2. In a `documentclass` without floats, like `beamer`, you don't need to specify the positioning with `[ht]`

Comment: I'm sure the problem is with me, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: @Great Did you try with exactly the document from my answer? If yes, which version are you using? I am on texlive 2015.

Comment: I found the problem, I had a package:\usepackage[magyar]{babel} that I was told is necessary for my language, but it turned out that was a lie, without that it finally works, thanks for your help.

Comment: @Great Btw, can you please check your old questions, if the answers given there solves them eventually accept them if they do? Referring to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/251117/how-to-center-the-numbers and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/251503/how-can-i-add-more-line-to-my-beamer-presentation-title-side

Comment: https://sourceforge.net/p/latex-caption/tickets/41/